# read input from command return error script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have the following shell script which read data from command.

```
while read _ host ip time _; do
    echo $host
done < <(traceroute yahoo.fr)
```

the above source code return script error

```
./traceroute_launch: line 33: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
./traceroute_launch: line 33: `done < <(traceroute yahoo.fr)'
```

I copied the above source code on the shell and it works. But when I run it from script file I got the above error.

What I m missing

Answer (score 0):

The process substitution (`<()`) is `bash`-ism, not defined by POSIX.

So this is failing giving syntax error when you are trying to run inside the script using `sh` (presumably `dash`?), not `bash`.

You can have the shebang of the script set as `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to get the script interpreted by `bash`, and get the process substitution working.